# Create file server side and save it from client side by selecting folder

Tags: java, sql, spring-mvc, text-files, mule

im using spring mvc (client side) and ESB Mule flows (server side) which includes java components (classes).

Thing is that i got an "EXPORT" button in the client side, when clicked that triggers a SELECT * FROM table in ESB Mule, then creates a file server side with that information inside the java component:

This is the mule flow (Added generic names)

```
<flow name="EXPORT_TABLE_DATA">
    <ajax:servlet-inbound-endpoint channel="/export_table" responseTimeout="10000"/>
    <jdbc:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
          queryKey="export_table_data"
          queryTimeout="-1"
          connector-ref="ExtendedRoutingConnector">
        <jdbc:query key="export_routing_table_data"
                    value="SELECT * FROM table_name"/>
    </jdbc:outbound-endpoint>
    <component class="com.web.esb.component.GenerateRoutingTableTextFile" />
</flow>
```

This is inside of the `GenerateRoutingTableTextFile` Java component.

```
File dir = new File("routing-data");
if(!dir.exists()) {
    dir.mkdir();            
}
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(dir +"/" + "tabledata_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".txt"));
ArrayList<CaseInsensitiveHashMap> arrayList; 
try{
    arrayList = (ArrayList) eventContext.getMessage().getPayload();
    for(CaseInsensitiveHashMap map : arrayList){
        writer.write("** data line from SQL Query **"));
        writer.newLine();
    }
    writer.close();
} catch (Exception e){
    writer.close();
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return writer;
```

Thing is that, this is creating a folder inside the project. What i would like to do is send the file to client side so the Save As... pop up will come up.

How can i push it to the client side? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the client should not ave control over server. they both should be independent

Comment: I know, but is there a way to get the file from the server? like when you are working with servlets... if the extension can't be handled by the browser it just lets you save the file with a "Save As..." pop up. I did it with excel files (.xls) long time ago. But i'm not working with servlets now.

Comment: Can you post your mule config?

Comment: @Daniel done daniel, i've added the ESB Mule flow.

Comment: Why using AJAX and not just plain HTTP? You intend to stream the data through a client-side AJAX call?

Comment: Nope D: i'm not using ajax. 
Now im having another problem with this. Im going to post another question and lets see if someone can help me with that option.